# Large JSON object passed to web worker doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, web-worker

I've been working on a game. However, it uses collision detection. There are 2 teams: green and red. There are 1000 particles on each team. Each particle on each team checks for collisions with every particle on the other team every frame. It slows down the javascript a lot, so I implemented a web worker. Every frame, the vertices of both particle systems(A vertex is a particle) are stringified into and then parsed. Each frame it runs this code:

```
particlesJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( { "a" : Points.vertices, "b" : Points2.vertices }));
```

particlesJSON is already defined. When I put this into console, it works and shows me this:

```
Object { a: Array[1000], b: Array[1000] }
```

For clarification there are 1000 vertices in each particle system(there are 2). Each vertex has an x, y, and z. There is also also a vel(velocity) object as another vector. There is also a float called speed to determine how fast the object will be moving. Vel, is more of a direction. The entire JSON object is then passed to the web worker. Web Worker code:

```
self.addEventListener("message", handleCollisions );
var collidedParticles = [],//an array to store that is sent to main UI thread, telling which particles to remove.
  particleSys1,
  particleSys2;
function handleCollisions(e) {
  particleSys1 = e.a;
  particleSys2 = e.b;
  for ( var i = 0; i < particleSys1.length; i++ ) {
    particle = particleSys1[i];
    for ( var j = 0; j < particleSys2.length; j++ ) {
      particle2 = particleSys2[j];
      if ( dist(particle.x, particle.y, particle.z, particle2.x, particle2.y, particle2.z) < 15) {
        if ( particle.y == 0 ) {
          collidedParticles.push(particle);
          collidedParticles.push(particle2);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  self.postMessage(collidedParticles);
}

function dist( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 ) {//Distance calculator
    var dx = x1 - x2;
    var dy = y1 - y2;
    var dz = z1 - z2;

    return Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz );
}
```

I've looked at so many different pages without finding the answer. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: One optimization you can do is pull out ur inner condition out side the second loop `if ( particle.y == 0 ) {`

Comment: "*Every frame, the vertices of both particle systems are stringified into and then parsed*" - WTH would you do that?!

Comment: When you are passing objects to a web worker, they already will implicitly be cloned.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( ... ))` is completely unnecessary. Just remove both functions, It should work without them.